# Intermediate value in simple Haskell function

Tags: haskell

I need a function to double every other number in a list. This does the trick:

```
doubleEveryOther :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleEveryOther []         = []
doubleEveryOther (x:[])     = [x]
doubleEveryOther (x:(y:zs)) = x : 2 * y : doubleEveryOther zs
```

However, the catch is that I need to double every other number starting *from the right* - so if the length of the list is even, the first one will be doubled, etc.

I understand that in Haskell it's tricky to operate on lists backwards, so my plan was to reverse the list, apply my function, then output the reverse again. I have a `reverseList` function:

```
reverseList :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
reverseList  [] = []
reverseList  xs = last xs : reverseList (init xs)
```

But I'm not quite sure how to implant it inside my original function. I got to something like this:

```
doubleEveryOther :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleEveryOther []         = []
doubleEveryOther (x:[])     = [x]
doubleEveryOther (x:(y:zs)) =
 | rev_list = reverseList (x:(y:zs))
 |  rev_list = [2 * x, y] ++ doubleEveryOther zs
```

I'm not exactly sure of the syntax of a function that includes intermediate values like this.

In case it's relevant, this is for Exercise 2 in [CIS 194 HW 1](http://cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/hw/01-intro.pdf).

Comment: Hint: keep the old `doubleEveryOther`, and write a new function with a new name that combines `reverseList` and `doubleEveryOther`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very simple combination of the two functions you've already created:

```
doubleEveryOtherFromRight = reverseList . doubleEveryOther . reverseList
```

Note that your `reverseList` is actually already defined in the standard Prelude as [reverse](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:reverse). so you didn't need to define it yourself.

I'm aware that the above solution isn't very efficient, because both uses of `reverse` need to pass through the entire list. I'll leave it to others to suggest more efficient versions, but hopefully this illustrates the power of function composition to build more complex computations out of simpler ones.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks very much! I'm sure there are more efficient ways but I just needed to get over that bump.

Answer (score 4):

As Lorenzo points out, you can make one pass to determine if the list has an odd or even length, then a second pass to actually construct the new list. It might be simpler, though, to separate the two tasks.

```
doubleFromRight ls = zipWith ($) (cycle fs) ls -- [f0 ls0, f1 ls1, f2 ls2, ...]
   where fs = if odd (length ls)
              then [(*2), id]
              else [id, (*2)]
```

---

So how does this work? First, we observe that to create the final result, we need to apply one of two function (`id` or `(*2)`) to each element of `ls`. `zipWith` can do that if we have a list of appropriate functions. The interesting part of its definition is basically

```
zipWith f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : zipWith f xs ys
```

When `f` is `($)`, we're just applying a function from one list to the corresponding element in the other list.

We want to zip `ls` with an infinite alternating list of `id` and `(*2)`. The question is, which function should that list start with? It should always *end* with `(*2)`, so the starting item is determined by the length of `ls`. An odd-length requires us to start with `(*2)`; an even one, `id`.

Comment: Any reason for using an if-then-else instead of guards?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the other solutions show you how to either use the building blocks you already have or building blocks available in the standard library to build your function. I think it's also instructive to see how you might build it from scratch, so in this answer I discuss one idea for that.

Here's the plan: we're going to walk all the way to the end of the list, then walk back to the front. We'll build our new list during our walk back from the end. The way we'll build it as we walk back is by alternating between (multiplicative) factors of 1 and 2, multiplying our current element by our current factor and then swapping factors for the next step. At the end we'll return both the final factor and the new list. So:

```
doubleFromRight_ :: Num a => [a] -> (a, [a])
doubleFromRight_ [] = (1, [])
doubleFromRight_ (x:xs) =
    -- not at the end yet, keep walking
    let (factor, xs') = doubleFromRight_ xs
    -- on our way back to the front now
    in (3-factor, factor*x:xs')
```

If you like, you can write  a small wrapper that throws away the factor at the end.

```
doubleFromRight :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
doubleFromRight = snd . doubleFromRight_
```

In ghci:

```
> doubleFromRight [1..5]
[1,4,3,8,5]
> doubleFromRight [1..6]
[2,2,6,4,10,6]
```

Modern practice would be to hide the helper function `doubleFromRight_` inside a `where` block in `doubleFromRight`; and since the slightly modified name doesn't actually tell you anything new, we'll use the community standard name internally. Those two changes might land you here:

```
doubleFromRight :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
doubleFromRight = snd . go where
    go [] = (1, [])
    go (x:xs) = let (factor, xs') = go xs in (3-factor, factor*x:xs')
```

An advanced Haskeller might then notice that `go` fits into the shape of a fold and write this:

```
doubleFromRight :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
doubleFromRight = snd . foldr (\x (factor, xs) -> (3-factor, factor*x:xs)) (1,[])
```

But I think it's perfectly fine in this case to stop one step earlier with the explicit recursion; it may even be more readable in this case!

Comment: Thanks for this answer, Daniel . Apologies for the dim question but what exactly does `(3-factor, factor*x:xs')` do?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander `3-factor` and `factor*x` are just subtraction and multiplication, respectively; `:` is the function that prepends an element to a list; and `(,)` is the constructor for pairs (aka tuples if you prefer that name).

Comment: So does `3 - factor` move us back three steps in the list?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander Nope. It's just a trick to alternate between 1 and 2: `3-1 = 2` and `3-2 = 1`. So if the current factor is `1`, then `3-factor` is the new factor of `2`; and if the current factor is `2`, then `3-factor` is the new factor of `1`.

Comment: Ah, now I see. While @Robin Zigmond's answer was what I was looking for, reading your answer slowly/asking for clarification taught me a lot of new stuff. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have to work on consecutive terms in a list, `zip` with a list comprehension is an easy way to go. It takes two lists and returns a list of tuples, so you can either zip the list with its tail or make it indexed. What i mean is

```
doubleFromRight :: [Int] -> [Int]
doubleFromRight ls = [if (odd i == oddness) then 2*x else x | (i,x) <- zip [1..] ls]
    where
      oddness = odd . length $ ls
```

This way you count every element, starting from 1 and if the index has the same parity as the last element in the list (both odd or both even), then you double the element, else you leave it as is.

I am not 100% sure this is more efficient, though, if anyone could point it out in the comments that would be great

Comment: Better yet, use `zipWith ($) listOfFuncs ls`, where `listOfFuncs` is either `cycle [id, (*2)]` or `cycle [(*2), id]`, depending on whether the list is odd or not.

Comment: @chepner, that's a very neat, understandable and (as far as I can tell) efficient solution, you should post it as an answer yourself

Answer (score 1):

If we really want to avoid calculating the length, we can define

```
doubleFromRight :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
doubleFromRight xs = zipWith ($)
                       (foldl' (\a _ -> drop 1 a) (cycle [(2*), id]) xs)
                       xs
```

This pairs up the input list with the cycled *infinite* list of functions, `[(*2), id, (*2), id, .... ]`. then it skips along them both. when the first list is finished, the second is in the appropriate state to be - again - applied, pairwise, - on the second! This time, for real.

So in effect it does *measure* the length (of course), it just doesn't count in integers but in the list elements so to speak.

If the length of the list is even, the first element will be doubled, otherwise the second, as you've specified in the question:

```
> doubleFromRight [1..4]
[2,2,6,4]

> doubleFromRight [1..5]
[1,4,3,8,5]
```

The `foldl'` function processes the list left-to-right. Its type is

```
foldl' :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
--        reducer_func    acc   xs    result
```

Comment: Can you clarify how this algorithm decides which to start with, if it doesn't calculate the length?

Comment: it pairs up the input list with the cycled *infinite* list of functions, `[(*2), id, (*2), id, .... ]`. then it skips along them both. when the first list is finished, the second is in the appropriate state to be - again - applied, pairwise, - on the second!

Comment: thanks for staying engaged. it can be hard to say what is or isn't immediately clear in my code. :)

Comment: Thank you for the help! The Haskell community (here and on IRC) is ridiculously patient and helpful to newbies.